# Calling class methods in a generic way, e.g. using instancetype?

Tags: objective-c, clang, instancetype

In Objective-C, is there a way to call class methods in a generic way on the current class?

For example, I would expect to be able to do something like

```
instancetype *myClass = [instancetype new];
```

But this doesn't work ("use of undeclared identifier `instancetype`").

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can do this using `self.class`, for example

```
UIView *myclass = [self.class new];
```